# ALEXA send response asynchronously through EVENTS gateway

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, alexa-voice-service, alexa-slot

I have followed all steps mentioned here https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/smarthome/send-events-to-the-alexa-event-gateway.html till retrieving the bearer token. But I would like to know exactly how do we send a asynchronous response to Alexa? If you see the example here

```
POST /v3/events HTTP/1.1
Host: api.amazonalexa.com
Authorization: Bearer access-token-from-Amazon
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "context": {
    "properties": [
    ]
  },
  "event": {
    "header": {
      "messageId": "abc-123-def-456",
      "correlationToken": "abcdef-123456",
      "namespace": "Alexa",
      "name": "Response",
      "payloadVersion": "3"
    },
    "endpoint": {
      "scope": {
        "type": "BearerToken",
        "token": "access-token-from-Amazon"
       },
       "endpointId" :  "endpoint-id"
    },
    "payload": {
    }
  }
}
```

There is a mention of **endpoint-id**? What is the endpoint-id for the alexa device itself? How can I send a response to alexa? I just want to send a "hello world" response which alexa will voice it out when I send it through an events gateway? Can anyone show me a sample? Thanks

Comment: Can anyone help me? Can you please post an example of a simple async Response to ALexa through the event gateway, all alexa has to do is voice out the response that's it.Many Thanks Please note I have reached till the part where Bearer token is received successfully and then access and refresh tokens too all are good.

Comment: Are you developing a Smart Home Skill or Custom Skill? Why do you want to send a response back to Alexa asynchronously? What are you trying to do? The event gateway is mainly used by Smart Home Skill developers to proactively report their device's state (e.g. user physically turned on a light switch) to Alexa. The `endpointId` is the ID of that smart home device.

Comment: @Christina Thanks. I'm using smart home skill model and custom skill model combination in  a single skill. When someone enables their skill I get the AcceptGrant ((I get all bearer token, access refresh all setup nicely here). When someone uses  Alexa it calls the lambda,  lambda sends a deferred response synchronously. Then after 15 seconds (The thing my lambda does will take about 15 seconds to complete) I would like to send the FINAL response to alexa using events gateway asynchronous. Is it possible?  or is there any other way to do it? Thanks again

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/device-apis/alexa-response.html#deferred), DeferredResponse is only supported for some interfaces. You would need to check the documentation of the Smart Home interface you're using to see if it's supported. Regardless, creating a single skill with both Smart Home and Custom skill model doesn't mean you can always control the TTS response. It depends on how the user interact with your product. If the user say "Alexa, turn on <your device name>", it's not possible to have Alexa say "hello world" back to the user.

Answer (score 0):

Hi When the Alexa Request is success instead of sending the response back to Alexa make the rest call to the Alexa Event Gateway, with the same payload.

Read more [here](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/smarthome/send-events-to-the-alexa-event-gateway.html).